# Python application giving error deployed through Docker

Tags: python, docker, sanic

I have python application which I am deploying through. Container is creating properly and it is up and running. But server is getting stop and throwing error.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt ./

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

# command to run on container start

CMD ["python3", "apps/main.py", "start", "--config", "config.yml"]
```

Error I am getting in the logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 556, in serve
    http_server = loop.run_until_complete(server_coroutine)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1775, in create_server
OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('::1', 8000, 0, 0): cannot assign requested address
[2021-09-17 12:50:51 +0000] [97] [INFO] Server Stopped
```

Can someone please explain if there is any issue with dockerfile or the CMD command that I have define.

First attempt to update host to 0.0.0.0 but doesn't work.

Error:

```
[2021-09-17 15:02:24 +0000] [98] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://localhost:8000
[2021-09-17 15:02:24 +0000] [98] [DEBUG] Sanic auto-reload: enabled
[2021-09-17 15:02:24 +0000] [98] [DEBUG] Sanic debug mode: enabled
[2021-09-17 15:02:24 +0000] [98] [ERROR] Unable to start server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 556, in serve
    http_server = loop.run_until_complete(server_coroutine)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1775, in create_server
OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('::1', 8000, 0, 0): cannot assign requested address
[2021-09-17 15:02:24 +0000] [98] [INFO] Server Stopped
```

Comment: can you please add `docker ps -a` output?

Comment: f79c123f5547   smt:latest                                   "python3 smartinsigh…"   5 seconds ago        Up 4 seconds                0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp

Comment: and you're getting the error you added to the question in the container logs? if they're host os logs make notice of that

Comment: Yes, in the container logs only I am getting this error

Comment: what tutorial have you followed to create the sank app? have you tried running this server locally with the same commands?

Comment: Yes, I tried locally without docker it is running fine over there

Comment: try changing the `create_server` command to be like so `server = app.create_server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)`

Comment: if you'd add more of your code to the original question I'd be able to give a better advise. on a quick look maybe try changing DEFAULT_HOST to "0.0.0.0" instead of "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I tried changing it 0.0.0.0 but it didn't work. Cannot add much of the code here due to certain reasons

Comment: can you add to the question the new error? and at least a bigger part of the code that starts the server? the rest doesn't matter to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to '0.0.0.0' (all NICs) seemed to solve the issue after hardcoding that to the `app.start` function.
Before used to bind to ipv6 localhost address (`::1`)